# Communication between react and feathersjs

Tags: reactjs, client, backend, feathersjs

There exist a React client on a server. And also a Feathers backend on another server. What are the parts needed to communicate between the two. For example to pass a username and Password.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/server.html

It should answer all your questions